# INNER JOIN repetindo dados entre tableas

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde, tenho uma tabela clientes e planos que tem indice de chaves entre elas, e preciso listar todos os clientes e mostrar o nome dos planos caso o cliente tenha algum plano vinculado. Os clientes q não tem plano vinculado aparecem com o plano repetido da linha anterior.

```
SELECT clientes.id, clientes.chave,  clientes.chave_plano, clientes.chave_sistema, planos.chave AS c_plano, planos.nome AS nome_plano FROM clientes  JOIN planos ON clientes.chave_plano = planos.chave OR clientes.chave_plano IS NULL;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem me ajudar ?

LEFT OUTER JOIN
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

inserir a descrição da imagem aqui

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você quer listar todos os clientes e quando não tiver plano associado os dados do plano sejam NULL então utilize LEFT OUTER JOIN e não INNER JOIN.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda, mas o LEFT OUTER JOIN também repetiu os nome do plano, coloquei uma imagem com o LEFT na minha pergunta

Comment: Poste a definição das tabelas envolvidas juntamente com a indicação das chaves primárias e estrangeiras. Tire esta condição `OR clientes.chave_plano IS NULL`.

Comment: cloquei na pergunta as imagens. se remover OR clientes.chave_plano IS NULL não lista os cliente sem planos vinculados

Comment: Aqui no SOpt postar imagens não é uma prática adequada. Veja: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70).

Comment: Com INNER JOIN certamente não listará, com LEFT OUTER JOIN certamente listará.

Comment: Agora funcionou, obrigado. Obrigado pelo manual, sou novo aqui :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `JOIN` não é adequado para o que deseja.

Ao estabelecer duas condições para o `JOIN` com o conectivo `OR` ele irá fazer a junção caso uma das duas seja verdadeira, ou as duas.

Isso faz retornar linhas repetidas, pois o `JOIN` faz um produto cartesiano e seleciona somente as linhas que atendem à condição (para ver isso teste com um `JOIN` sem condição).

Recomendo usar um `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
(SELECT clientes.id, clientes.chave,  clientes.chave_plano, clientes.chave_sistema, planos.chave AS c_plano, planos.nome AS nome_plano FROM clientes  JOIN planos ON clientes.chave_plano = planos.chave)

UNION

(SELECT clientes.id, clientes.chave,  clientes.chave_plano, clientes.chave_sistema, NULL AS c_plano, NULL AS nome_plano FROM clientes WHERE clientes.chave_plano IS NULL)
)

ORDER BY id;
```

(Eu não testei aqui para ver se a sintaxe está correta, mas a ideia é essa)

---

Ou você pode também criar um plano com chave nula (se puder).

---

Ou ainda (o que eu acho mais adequado) seria criar um plano `Não possui plano contratado`, ou coisa parecida. E tratar isto na sua aplicação cliente.